# Insert number to textbox and get data to file using binarywriter or streamwriter

Tags: visual-studio

I am writing code in c#. I need value of my textbox written to file, im using var value = Convert.ToByte(textbox1.Test) . So I need The 1st 3 bytes should be fixed and rest should be using my textbox value. Is it possible to use binarywriter and streamwriter together eg: binarywriter.write(fix byte) a& streamwriter.write(value from text)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BinaryWriter` adds a length prefix to everything you write to allow it to be read by `BinaryReader`.

If you want to write raw data, use `Stream` (with `byte[]`) or `StreamWriter` (with strings, but think about encodings) directly.

Comment: I need 1st 3 specific bytes and rest 4 bytes depends on value I insert in my textbox!! Eg: if I insert 27 in my textbox I should get 32 and 37 in my file.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert bytes to hex strings? (`"32 37"`)

Comment: Yes, I need to get 32 37 when I use binary write. I cannot use stream as my 1st 3 bytes are fixed.

Comment: You aren't asking to write binary; you asking to convert to bytes (using `Encoding`), convert those bytes to strings, then write text.

Comment: When I convert byte to string I’m not getting accepted answer. The 1st 3 bytes should be fixed and rest should be using my textbox value. Is it possible to use binarywriter and streamwriter together eg: binarywriter.write(fix byte) a& streamwriter.write(value from text)???